# How to create and print an array

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a list of array call the Jobarray, however, when I trying doing that, netlogo returns the following error:

```
  Extension exception: not an array: 0
  error while job 470 running ARRAY:ITEM
  called by procedure JOBLIST
  called by procedure PLACE-JOBS
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'Setup'
```

These are my code

```
to setup 
ca 
place-jobs 
print Jobarray 
reset-ticks 
end

to set-job-index 
let columns 3 
let rows-job Number-Of-Jobs set   
Jobarray array:from-list n-values rows-job [array:from-list n-values columns [0]] 
end

to Joblist [#col #row #val] 
array:set (array:item Jobarray #row) #col #val 
end

to draw-pods
  ;draw pods area
  ask patches with [(pxcor mod 4 = 2 or pxcor mod 4 = 3) and (pycor mod (Pod-size + 2) > 1 and pycor < (max-pycor - 4))]
  [
  sprout 1
    [
      set shape "square"
      set color blue
      stamp
      die
    ]
  set meaning "pods"
  ]
end

to place-jobs
  let Job-index 0 ;; row of list; 0 == 1
  ask n-of (Number-Of-Jobs) patches with [meaning = "pods"]
    [
      sprout-jobs 1
      [
        Joblist 0 Job-index who
        Joblist 1 Job-index pxcor
        Joblist 2 Job-index pycor
        set Job-index (Job-index + 1)
        set shape "square"
        set color pink
        set job-value 1
        stamp
;        die
      ]
    set meaning "jobs"
    set Jobnum (count jobs-on patches with [meaning = "jobs"])
    ]
end
```

Can anyone helps me explain why and how can I fix it? I have tried it on searching google and also the dictionary but still not understand why.
Sincerely,
Minh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Jobarray` isn't being initialized. I think you forgot to call `set-job-index` when you create you're agents.

Comment: No problem! Make sure to mark the answer correct so that other's know this question has been answered.